# SQL date type range not according to spec?

Tags: sql, datetime, date-range, isnull

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(SQL.90).aspx) the range for date datatype is January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999

In SQL2005 the following is interesting:

```
declare @date as datetime
SET @date = '1/1/1901 12:00:00 AM'
SELECT @date

if (isnull(@date,0) = 0) SELECT 'date is null' ELSE SELECT 'date not null'
```

change the date to `'1/1/1901 12:00:00 AM'` and suddenly `isnull(@date,0)` is 0.

What am I missing?

(Edit) fixed daterange for sql2005, link to sql2005 BOL

Comment: It's not relevant to what you have actually posted, but note that the MSDN page you linked to is for the 'date' datatype (new in SQL 2008), whereas your code uses 'datetime'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @date as datetime
SET @date = '1/1/1901 12:00:00 AM'

SELECT @date, CASE WHEN @date IS NULL THEN 'date is null' ELSE 'date not null' END
```

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @date as datetime
SET @date = '1/1/1901 12:00:00 AM'
SELECT @date

if @date is null SELECT 'date is null' ELSE SELECT 'date not null'
```

`ISNULL()` is a conversion function. It is not the check if a value is `NULL`.

A date has a numeric representation. The numeric representation of `'1/1/1901 12:00:00 AM'` happens to be `0`, on SQL Server.

You can't compare the result of `ISNULL(@date,0)` to `0` without losing the ability to distinguish between a date that could be represented as `0` and a date that is `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

The line of code below is misleading:

```
if (isnull(@date,null) = 0) SELECT 'date is null' ELSE SELECT 'date not null'
```

This line returns 0 if `@date` == 0, *not* when it is null. The date you've specified is stored as 0 in a datetime.

```
SELECT convert(datetime, 0)
```

to see what I mean!

Comment: You are right, but still, run the code. see what I mean - '1/1/1901 12:00:00 AM' returns a different result than '1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM' on isnull()

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
declare @date as datetime
SET @date = '1/1/1901 12:00:00 AM'
SELECT @date, CONVERT(numeric(9,3), @date) as DateValue
if (isnull(@date,0) = 0) SELECT 'date is zero' ELSE SELECT 'date not equal to zero (THIS PRINTS)'
if (isnull(@date,0) = 365) SELECT 'date is 365 (THIS PRINTS)' ELSE SELECT 'date not equal to zero'
if (@date = 365) SELECT 'date is 365 (THIS PRINTS)' ELSE SELECT 'date not 365'

SET @date = '1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM'
SELECT @date, CONVERT(numeric(9,3), @date) as DateValue
if (isnull(@date,0) = 0) SELECT 'date is equal to Zero (THIS PRINTS)' ELSE SELECT 'date not null'
if (@date = 0) SELECT 'date is equal to Zero (THIS PRINTS)' ELSE SELECT 'date not null'
```

There is **nothing** wrong with ISNULL nor with COALESCE. 
The problem is that you are comparing with zero, and you fool yourself into thinking that the ISNULL kicked in.
Try my code, and see that ISNULL returns the correct value.